# How can I fix this express and filesystem error on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I have an express project generated with the express generator. As you know, the core of the server is in the bin folder, in a file called **www**. So far so good. I try to add an self-signed TLS certificate to my site (is in local), so instead of using the http module, I use https.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('server:server');
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '443');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./security/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./security/cert.pem')
}

var server = https.createServer(options, app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

That is my configuration. And this is my directory:

[image]

As you can see, I have the certificates inside a folder called security, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

I have removed **./** from the routes but I'm getting same error. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike modules that you require, all other file paths are relative to the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). Since you execute the program via `./bin/www` then the files are expected to be inside `server/security` instead of `server/bin/security`. If, on the other hand, you do `cd bin; ./www` your program should execute normally.

The reason for this is simply common sense. Imagine you want to write a program to copy files in node.js. The file name you provide to your program **has** to be relative to the directory you're currently in in the console. Otherwise it's impossible to write such a program without always providing absolute paths.

To get the behaviour you want, use the `__dirname` variable:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'security/key.pem'))
```